# Is it now OK to remove this uninstall code from my Inno Setup install script?

Tags: inno-setup

Here is a brief history of my installers:

Over the years I had **INSTALL-A** and **INSTALL-B**.

Both of those installers included the same *embedded* **INSTALL-C**.

When *either* application INSTALL-A or INSTALL-B is **uninstalled** it performs this action:

```
procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
var
  strCalendarInterfacesUninstallPath: String;
  iResultCode: Integer;
begin
if CurUninstallStep = usUninstall then
begin
    if (RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                            'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{xxxx}_is1',
                         'QuietUninstallString', strCalendarInterfacesUninstallPath )) then
    begin
      if SuppressibleMsgBox(CustomMessage('UninstallCalendarInterfaces'), mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO, idNo) = idYes then
      begin
        if (not Exec('>', strCalendarInterfacesUninstallPath, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, iResultCode)) then
          SuppressibleMsgBox(SysErrorMessage(iResultCode), mbError, MB_OK, idOk);
      end;
    end;
end;
end;
```

In my recent releases of **INSTALL-B** I have changed the way it works and it **no longer** installs **INSTALL-C**. But I **still** have the uninstall code above in the installer.

The user **might** still have **INSTALL-A** on their computer. Of course, INSTALL-C can be uninstalled from the **control panel**.

So, is it now considered OK to just **remove** the uninstall code check from **INSTALL-B**?

Thanks.

PS. I apologise if this is a bit off topic for **StackOverflow**. But I can't work out the right place to ask this time of question. I have tried **CodeReview** before but I don't think that fits this question either.

Comment: What if the newer version of the INSTALL-B is installed over an old version that included the INSTALL-C?

Comment: This is why I am asking the question. ☺ Is it safest to just leave the check in there due to piggy backed upgrading?

Comment: Or remove the INSTALL-C on upgrade.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I can only do that if install a is not installed.

Comment: I do not understand that. If install A is installed, you do not want to uninstall C, when uninstalling B either, right? So you need to have a code to detect that A is installed, in place anyway, don't you?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Technically you are right. I got around that by asking the user.